# Rails 3 Engine & Static assets

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, static, assets, rails-engines

I'm building an engine I've bundled as a gem (gmaps4rails). I copied the /public of my engine in the /public of my rails app.

Everything works fine in development but fails to work in production: it appears static assets (of my engine & my main app) aren't found.

The logs tell the following (just an abstract):

```
Started GET "/javascripts/application.js?1286294679" for 127.0.0.1 at Wed Nov 24 00:22:20 +0100 2010

ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches "/javascripts/application.js"):


Rendered /Users/me/.rvm/rubies/ree-1.8.7-2010.02/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-3.0.3/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/routing_error.erb within rescues/layout (1.1ms)


Started GET "/stylesheets/gmaps4rails.css?1290554221" for 127.0.0.1 at Wed Nov 24 00:22:20 +0100 2010

ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches "/stylesheets/gmaps4rails.css"):
```

I've done a few things:

1. in my app's production.rb, I set:

   config.serve_static_assets = true

   This Solves the problem but is not elegant enough, I'd like to keep it to false and add configuration in the engine :)
2. I followed the advice  [here](http://piotrsarnacki.com/2010/09/14/mountable-engines/)  without success.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For performance reason, static assets serving is disabled in production mode. Your webserver should be configured to serve theses assets.

Look at this [discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/531189/rails-a-route-to-serve-static-assets-like-jpgs-etc) if your are using nginx as a webserver.

Answer (score 5):

In Rails 3.x try to set this in config/environments/production.rb

> config.serve_static_assets = true

By default Rails assumes you are using an assets server (lightttp, nginx or Apache)

Answer (score 4):

In your engine, replace:

```
initializer "static assets" do |app|
  app.middleware.use ::ActionDispatch::Static, "#{root}/public"
end
```

with:

```
initializer "static assets" do |app|
      app.middleware.insert_before(::ActionDispatch::Static, ::ActionDispatch::Static, "#{root}/public")
end
```

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried adding this to your Rails::Engine class:

```
initializer "static assets" do |app|
  app.middleware.use ::ActionDispatch::Static, "#{root}/public"
end
```

This will merge in your Gem's /public directory with the app at runtime.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I did try but it doesn't make any difference :)

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem mounting a Rails 3.1 engine. I was receiving blank assets in stage and production.

I found a solution at http://jonswope.com/2010/07/25/rails-3-engines-plugins-and-static-assets/comment-page-1/#comment-87 and tweaked it to suit Rails 3.1 asset locations:

```
initializer "static assets" do |app|
  app.middleware.insert_before ::Rack::Lock, ::ActionDispatch::Static, "#{root}/app/assets"
end
```

I imagine there is a more elegant way but my effort today didn't yield anything substantial.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know much about the way, gems are packaged/made. But why can't you copy the images/js/css stuff of your gems public folder into the apps public folder? I just did that and it worked for me. Is that not the done thing?

Comment: That means everyone who uses your gem has to manually copy the public files over to their main app... No it isn't the done thing!