# How to make a public folder in my rails plugin?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, plugins, public

How to make a public folder in my rails plugin?

For example, I have image in /my_rails_app/vendor/plugins/my_plugin/public/edit.gif but in http://localhost:3000/edit.gif i got routing error.

Comment: This could help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4266232/rails-3-engine-static-assets

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Directly you can't use it. Plugins /public are not merged with main /public folder by default. Generally on deployment it is common to map only main /public but nobody exposes plugin's to viewers.

You have to prepare rake task or generator which copies these files to apps /public folder.

Generally it may be possible to do some routing trickery but generally I'm not recommending it.

Comment: Definitely go for the generator or rake task. It is now common practice to use gems instead of plugins, and you have no idea where those are placed.

Answer (score 1):

You can put the image in **public/uploads/edit.gif**.

Then you can visit it via

> http:// localhost:3000/uploads/edit.gif

I tested on my rails server and it works.